# Installing python 3.5.2 - importerror

Tags: python

Installed Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit) for python 3.5.2 version. To check if everything was ok, at the command prompt I entered `conda –version`. 
Got the 2 separate import messages:

> Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of python
>   Cannot import name ‘quote’

We do have a python .exe program created in python 2.7 version and the folder with this program has python27.dll and pythoncom27.dll.

What should I do ?

Comment: try in different folder or remove folder with `python27.dll` and `pythoncom27.dll`

Comment: Both .dll files  are in C:\program files(x86)\durva\inSync folder.
I am afraid to delete the folder.

So I manually tried to delete python27.dll and pythoncom27.dll from the above folder and  message I get is ‘the action cannot be completed as the file is open in inSync.exe’